# In Oracle, How to handle NULL values when inserted to a Table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have one table, which has a filed. When I insert in that table with  the Empty value like '' or null, it should get converted to 'DUMMY-VALUE'.

```
--Have one table;
CREATE TABLE TEST  ( FIELD1 VARCHAR2(50) );

--When I insert ''
INSERT INTO TEST(FIELD1) VALUES('');

SELECT * FROM TEST
--Expected Result 'DUMMY-VALUE' but not NULL
```

I can apply `NVL('','DUMMY-VALUE')` in `INSERT` statement but I am allowed to change `CREATE` statement only.
For Now, I am handing this with `TRIGGER` but , wondering if there is any alternative in 11g however I know about `DEFAULT ON NULL` for oracle 12c.

Comment: How about making the column with a default value as `'DUMMY-VALUE'`? and inserting without that field if the values is NULL or empty?

Comment: No, default value will not work because NULL or '' will override the default value, However your suggestion will work only if the column name is not mentioned during insert.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
create table TEST  (FIELD1 VARCHAR2(50) default 'DUMMY-VALUE'  );
```

and when you want to insert
you should insert without that field if the values is NULL or empty

Comment: This will actually work only if FIELD1 is not provided in the insert statement. Passing NULL explicitly will bypass default value.

Comment: I meant this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02938/1. Note I can insert NULL into field1 explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (FIELD1 VARCHAR2(50) DEFAULT 'DUMMY-VALUE');
```

then use the `DEFAULT` keyword in the `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (FIELD1) VALUES (DEFAULT);
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d039b6/1)

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the good hint bob, but this will force to insert DEFAULT in all cases.